# ps command -o option gives "ERROR: Garbage option"

Tags: linux, ps

I have 2 suse-11 machine both has same kernel version.

> Linux version 2.6.32.59-0.7-default (geeko@buildhost) (gcc version
>   4.3.4 [gcc-4_3-branch revision 152973] (SUSE Linux) ) #1 SMP 2012-07-13 15:50:56 +0200

but in one machine below command works

> ps -u  test-o '%U %p %P %c'

but in other gives error like below

```
ERROR: Garbage option.
********* simple selection *********  ********* selection by list *********
-A all processes                      -C by command name
-N negate selection                   -G by real group ID (supports names)
-a all w/ tty except session leaders  -U by real user ID (supports names)
-d all except session leaders         -g by session OR by effective group name
-e all processes                      -p by process ID
T  all processes on this terminal     -s processes in the sessions given
a  all w/ tty, including other users  -t by tty
g  OBSOLETE -- DO NOT USE             -u by effective user ID (supports names)
r  only running processes             U  processes for specified users
x  processes w/o controlling ttys     t  by tty
*********** output format **********  *********** long options ***********
-o,o user-defined  -f full            --Group --User --pid --cols --ppid
-j,j job control   s  signal          --group --user --sid --rows --info
-O,O preloaded -o  v  virtual memory  --cumulative --format --deselect
-l,l long          u  user-oriented   --sort --tty --forest --version
-F   extra full    X  registers       --heading --no-heading --context
                    ********* misc options *********
-V,V  show version      L  list format codes  f  ASCII art forest
-m,m,-L,-T,H  threads   S  children in sum    -y change -l format
-M,Z  security data     c  true command name  -c scheduling class
-w,w  wide output       n  numeric WCHAN,UID  -H process hierarchy
```

Really not able to figure what is the problem here, can any one suggest me what could be wrong?

EDIT: which ps in both gives
/bin/ps

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I checked md5sum of both ps command, it was different. So i suspect some one might have replaced this bin without notice. Copied the ps command from correct source and problem solved